# Online resources of quality cartoons for toddler

Tags: toddler, television

while [watching TV may not be the ideal activity for our children](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/2607/is-there-any-consensus-among-researchers-concerning-the-effects-of-watching-tele) sometimes it is acceptable trade off.

Please help me find some legal online resources of quality cartoons for toddler.

In my case: language English, country UK, 1.5 year old happy toddler

Comment: In what language? And how old is your child?

Answer (score 6):

I'd agree that 1.5 is a bit young for watching much of anything.

Does your solution absolutely *have* to be online? I've had great fun buying DVDs of 70s and 80s children's series (and watching them with my kids!). The advantage is that they're often very short (5-10 minutes), self contained, and don't give rise to meltdowns when you stop them.

Another idea would be just pulling a few YouTube videos into a playlist, quite a few of those kids' programs are available [there](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fDWk0BCeblQ&feature=related).

I'd also consider looking for things that aren't 'stories' - at 1.5 I think they'd benefit more from music - there are some [really nice nursery rhyme](http://www.youtube.com/user/hooplakidz) videos on YouTube too.

Comment: The nursery rhymes are beautiful :)

Comment: @daniel.sedlacek, glad you like them :) You (sorry, I mean your child!) might like the Baby Einstein series - just ignore all the claims about boosting your child's IQ (or whatever)

Answer (score 5):

Depending on where you are, the BBC provide Children's BBC shows online (at **[CBeebies](http://www.bbc.co.uk/cbeebies/)** level for infants and **[CBBC](http://www.bbc.co.uk/cbbc/)** for older children) along with activities, games etc.

These may not be available outside the UK, I'm honestly not sure, but give them a try.

Answer (score 4):

We personally love the show "Peep and the Big Wide World" -- it encourages science and exploration for toddler age kids and up. Go to www.peepandthebigwideworld.com for free episodes, along with lots of learning games. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Kids don't know what's boring, and what's not until we teach them.  In my opinion it is wrong to assume that kids should only watch programs specifically designed for kids.  As such assuming that only cartoons will do is just going to enforce a stereotype that we have invented.  Certainly as children get older they want to graduate onto things that they can understand, and this is where kids TV comes into it's own, but at age 18/24 months they will find just the sight of someone talking just as stimulating as a cartoon.  I have found that rolling news channels* have a mix of colour and enough different faces/voices to keep my child entertained, also documentaries, animal/wildlife programs, the odd music video too.  Quiz shows, daft as they sound are brilliant, they have loads of people, animated shiny/sparkly scoreboards and such, and they'll love to learn to clap and laugh when the audience does etc.

If it has to be cartoons and online, then [cBeebies on BBC iPlayer](http://www.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/tv/cbeebies/20120209) is a good choice.  I personally like the recommendation by another user of kids DVDs, you can get stuff from when you were younger that your kids will enjoy as much as you did.  A friend bought "Button Moon" for her child and he loves it, plus they are much cheaper than some of the more modern programmes.

- Edit/Addition: This makes it sound like I sit them in front of SkyNews all day, I don't, but if they need 20 minutes downtime to mong then it might as well be something that I don't mind as well

Comment: I would hesitate about the news channels, actually. I am no expert in child psychology, but when an earthquake hits somewhere, I would not want my toddler to stare at the TV while the first reporters on scene show the injured and running people (and "breaking news" is not always a guideline, I have seen the running program interrupted for people to tell me a soccer-player got hurt during training...). Music and game shows sound safer in that regard.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to get stuff done, by a play-pen and put the baby in the play pen.

Don't put the TV on for a 16 month old toddler. Just don't.

Comment: even though I don't think it's so dramatic you get my +1